# Font is cropped on the bottom

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I imported a font in my CSS file with font-face and used it in my navigation menu.

The problem is that the letters are cropped at the bottom and it kinda ruins the font.

See for yourself: [dev.windbournecitizen.com/frontpage](http://dev.windbournecitizen.com/frontpage/)

It should look like this (with the changed text of course)
[image]

The font looks normal when you zoom in (with CTRL+Scroll) but not when you are not zommed in.

Is there any way to fix this?

The problem is encountered on Chrome 35 and Firefox 30 running on Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

By adding a stroke to the text it is possible to make the letters a bit bigger and the bottom of each letters is showing (almost) correctly. There are no more gaps.

I used this code to fix it:

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.5px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: #fe9f00;
```

It can also be (kinda) fixed using `text-shadow`. It can be used as an alternative for browser who do not support `-webkit-text-stroke`